# How to deselect tableview cell when selecting another tableview cell in the meantime?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I an doing a table view cell auto selecting for the first time by using

```
  [cell setSelected:YES animated:YES];
```

It select the cell programmatically for the first time. It works fine. Now I want to deselect that cell when i select another cell in the meantime. how can i do that. I know when i select a cell then tableview delegate method

```
 -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

is called and when deselect a cell then "did deselect row at index path" is called.

But the problem is i select the cell programmatically and when i select another cell then delegate method

```
 -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

doesn't call.

What should i do to solve this problem or what will be the logic to solve that problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of calling `setSelected:animated:` on the cell directly, call the `selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:` method of the table view to set the initial selection.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below method to deselect row:

```
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
```

You just need to stored index when it's selected. So you just need to check if you have selected indexpath then make it deselect.

**Take an object of NSIndexPath:**

```
NSIndexPath *currentSelectedPath;
```

**Update your didSelectRow method:**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(currentSelectedPath)
    {
        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:currentSelectedPath animated:YES];
    }
    currentSelectedPath = indexPath;

 // Do your other stuff
}
```